# Data Visualization in Python- relationship between 3 variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

I am currently working on a project where I am using machine learning to create a model that predicts which passengers survived the Titanic shipwreck.

I want to find the relationship between the gender of the person and their survival rate. I have one-hot encoded the gender column for the same.

So now I have 3 columns- Female( values 0 or 1), Male( values 0 or 1) and Survived( values 0 or 1). Can you suggest me a suitable graph to visualize and compare their relationship.

I tried scatter plot, but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: if you have single entry points with only 2 possible outcomes (survived/not survived) then visualizing each datapoint wont be informative. I would rather take statistics on the data and plot those numbers. take a look at [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for plotting libraries with tons of options.

Comment: I think using color code may help, for example, if you draw a scatterplot for all passengers and use blue for men red for women,  then you can compare the quantity of each color on 1 (survived) and zero(unsurvived)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, convert the data as lists,

1. survived
2. male
3. female

````
w = 0.4
survived = [.....]
male = [.....]
female = [......]

bar1 = np.arange(len(x))
bar2 = [i+w for i in bar1]

plt.bar(bar1,male,w,label="Male")
plt.bar(bar2,female,w,label="Female")

plt.xlabel("Name a label, Survived")
plt.ylabel("Name a label, Gender")
plt.title("Gender Vs Survived")
plt.legend()
plt.show()```
````